# On decomposition of the space of automorphic forms (via central characters)

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathbb{A}$ be its adele. For simplicity, we assume $G$ is a connected reductive group.

Given a unitary central character $\chi: Z_{G}(F)\backslash Z_{G}(\mathbb{A}) \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, we may define $L^{2}(G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}), \chi)$ to be the subspace of $L^{2}(G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}))$ consisting of functions $\phi$ such that $\phi(zg) = \omega(z)\phi(g)$.

> Question 1: Is there a decomposition like $L^{2}(G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A})) = \hat{\bigoplus_{\chi}} L^{2}(G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}),\chi)$ ? Or something like this at least for discrete spectrum?

If this is wildly false, I hope to know the reason why some authors consider the space $L^{2}(G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}), \chi)$ (or the other version, $\mathcal{A}(G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}), \chi)$, the space of automorphic forms with central characters $\chi$).

The previous question is motivated by the special case when $G = T$, a torus. For simplicity, we assume $T$ is anisotropic. In this case, the above decomposition does make sense. Equivalently, the space of automorphic forms $\mathcal{A}(T(F)\backslash T(\mathbb{A}))$ (denoted by $\mathcal{A}(T)$ onwards) should admit a decomposition into an algebraic direct sum $\mathcal{A}(T) = \bigoplus_{\chi} \mathbb{C}_{\chi}$.

> Question 2: How can we show this directly, without appealing to Peter-Weyl theorem or the $L^{2}$ stuffs at all?

Perhaps this sounds dumb, but I find it difficult to make sure **what "automorphic form" means for tori**. I understand there are several conditions for a function to be automorphic: smoothness, moderate growth, $K$-finiteness and $\mathfrak{Z}$-finiteness. Certainly, automorphic forms include all unitary Hecke characters, but how about the rest?

> Question 3: What does a general automorphic form of torus $T$ look like?

Comment: If you replace the direct sum by a direct integral, the statement becomes correct by vary general reasons.